How to verify every contraction satisfies the given statement in the question

Problem: Let $X$ be a complete metric space and $\phi:X\to X$ be continuous. There is a function $f:X\to[0,\infty)$ satisfying
$d(x,\phi(x))\leq f(x)-f(\phi(x))$ for all $x\in X$. Show that every
contraction $\phi$ on $X$ satisfies the above statement.


My attempt:
Note: $d(\phi(x),\phi(y))\leq c\cdot d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X,c<1$
Let $f(x)=d(x,x_0)$ for some fixed point $x_0$. $(1)d(x,\phi(x))\leq d(x,x_0)+d(x_0,\phi(x))$. And $(2)f(x)-f(\phi(x))=d(x,x_0)-d(\phi(x),x_0)\geq d(x,x_0)-c\cdot d(x,x_0)=(1-c)d(x,x_0)$.
However, I can't think of any way to connect (1) and (2). Is my direction correct?
Thanks a lot!

You’re on the right track. Your solution hasn't yet used the fact that $X$ is a complete metric space, so let's proceed in that direction.
Let $c<1$ be such that $d(\phi(x),\phi(y))\leq cd(x,y)$. Since $\phi$ is a contraction on a complete metric space, it has a unique fixed point $x^*$.
Now define $f$ similarly to how you defined it, by
$$f(x)=\frac{1+c}{1-c} d(x,x^*)$$
Then it follows that
\begin{align*}
d(x,\phi(x))&\leq d(x,x^*)+d(\phi(x),x^*)\\
&\leq d(x,x^*)+cd(x,x^*)\\
&=(1+c)d(x,x^*)\\
&=(1-c)\frac{1+c}{1-c}d(x,x^*)\\
&= \frac{1+c}{1-c}d(x,x^*)-c\frac{1+c}{1-c}d(x,x^*)\\
&\leq \frac{1+c}{1-c}d(x,x^*)-\frac{1+c}{1-c}d(\phi(x),x^*)\\
&=f(x)-f(\phi(x))
\end{align*}
